# get content of the className in the scss file

Tags: javascript, sass

I have scss file and I want to parse it and get the content of the class which I choose (dynamically) and if should return all the content of the specified class.

```
.styles-module--ctaArrow--JtKM2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 55px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 38px;
  transition: width .25s ease-in-out
}

@media (max-width: calc(992px - 1px)) {
  .styles-module--ctaArrow--JtKM2 {
    margin-top: 22px
  }
}

.styles-module--ctaArrowLine--2Lcej {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  height: 4px;
  background: #0058ff
}

.styles-module--ctaArrowIcon--1AFVc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: right .25s ease-in-out
}
```

I want to get the content of the class `styles-module--ctaArrowLine--2Lcej` which is

```
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  height: 4px;
  background: #0058ff
```

if there is any NPM package that will be great.

Comment: In what context do you want to extract the body of a rule? How do need to use it? The question currently is quite fuzzy.

Comment: that is for the reverse engineering of the some code. I am making the tool which reverse engineer some website.